# Google Maps Drawing on Mobile loses Draggable

Tags: google-maps, mobile, touch

I am trying to use google maps to allow a user to create multiple editabled/draggable polygons. Everything works fine from a desktop browser, but on a mobile/touch device all polygons are no longer draggable once a user adds a new polygon to the map. Polygons loaded on the map during initialize are draggable as expected.

I know touch events are not really supported by the google maps api, but is there a workaround I can do?

Simplified example:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new          google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 5,
  center: {lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268},
  mapTypeId: 'terrain'
});

var triangleCoords = [
  {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
  {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
  {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
  {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
];

// Construct the polygon.
var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: triangleCoords,
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: 0.35,
  draggable: true
});
bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
   drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
   drawingControl: true,
   drawingControlOptions: {
     position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
     drawingModes: ['polygon']
   },
   polygonOptions: {
     fillColor: '#ffff00',
     fillOpacity: 1,
     strokeWeight: 5,
     draggable: true,
     zIndex: 10000
    }
 });
 drawingManager.setMap(map);

 google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (e) {
   drawingManager.setOptions({
      drawingMode: null
   });
 });  

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

https://codepen.io/cyberjus/pen/XEVoer

Upon load from a mobile device, the first polygon is draggable, but once another polygon is drawn, neither can be dragged anymore. I am testing on an actual iPad, so I dont know if it is IOS specific or not.

Comment: What is the version of iOS and browser that you are using? Do note that the current and previous major version of Safari and only the current version of Chrome are supported, as per the [Javascript API browser support documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport#ios)

Comment: iOS 11.2.6 (will try 11.3 as well) and Chrome 65.0.3325.152. I also tried on Safari and get the same behavior. This is a new iPad build just for testing this, so Chrome is pretty much the only non-default thing installed.

Comment: Do you want to use the map in webpage or hybrid application like Apache Cordova?

Comment: Webpage and mobile browser (safari or chrome)

Comment: is this issue solved?

Comment: Still experiencing this issue.  Has anyone found a fix or workaround?

Comment: Link to the issue in Google's issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122961176

Comment: I am also looking for such functionality.  I see Zillow.com implemented a similar solution that allows one to draw a polygon freehand.   I tried using the touchstart, touchmove and touched events but the google maps addListener does not support these events.